# asp.net mvc slow response every 45 seconds

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, principalcontext

I have an MVC 4 app which is performing a slow request roughly every 45 seconds. It's normally 200ms and all requests will be 200ms for about 45 seconds before there is one for about 4500ms. Then back to 200ms.

I have no caching set up. 
I am however using a PrincipalContext to query AD.

I was wondering if anyone had any idea before I start setting up some profiling on the calls.

quick:

[image: quick]

slow:

[image: slow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Pinch, but the problem was Active Domain and PrincipalContext. [See the solution here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/20eb50e9-3e68-4d29-bcdd-a4fc166b9c00/adlds-very-slow-roundtrip-to-servermailslotnetnetlogon?forum=winserverDS), I turned off NetBIOS over TCP/IP and everything is running much better now.

Though I was displaying menu items based on the roles a user has, perhaps I'll cache these somewhere so I don't have to query AD every request.